# Nicely written check for numbers that can be null in java

Tags: java, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have an application where I need to handle a lot of numbers (Integers or Longs) comming from external sources.

The numbers can be null. In case they are null I *always* need to convert them to 0.

The problem seems trivial, but I don't want to write hundreds of times:

```
if (someNumber == null) {
    someNumber = 0;
}
```

I don't like it for two reasons:

1. I don't like to write three lines of code for such simple task, especially because I need to do it many times
2. I don't like to to "mutate" someNumber (assign new value to someNumber variable)

I tried some other ways which can be seen here:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer zeroOrNull = new Random().nextBoolean() ? 0 : null;


    // version1: this is nasty (I already mentioned why)
    if (zeroOrNull == null) {
      zeroOrNull = 0;
    }

    // version2: this seems to much for so simple task...
    zeroOrNull = Optional.ofNullable(zeroOrNull).orElseGet(() -> 0);

    // version3: creating an util might be considerable. Is there already such predefined util ?
    zeroOrNull = MyUtil.getValueOrZero(zeroOrNull); // returns value or )

    System.out.println(zeroOrNull); // I want 0 here in case of null


  }
```

What is the preffered and nice way to do such "test for null/conversion to 0" ?  Any chance to do this conversion implicitly?

Comment: When you get the numbers from the external source, you must have some code that reads them into Integers. That code must distingish between nulls and not nulls anyway (for example, if you use Integer.parseInt(string), it will only work for non-empty Strings), so you can convert the nulls to 0 in that code.

Comment: It seems, you already mentioned all alternatives. All of them look ok, but their necessity is obviously a symptom for a much heavier design problem. If you design a method that simply cannot accept a `null` value, then just do not allow it. Change the calling code at first to not send in `null`. If you still must distinguish between _present_ and _absent_, then use `java.util.Optional`, but as a method parameter (not inside the method for its implementation).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing `if (someNumber == null) {
    someNumber = 0;
} ` that is exactly what you should do.

Comment: @Eran: This would be an option. The problem is that I would need to do such conversion in every place where I get this numbers. Maybe this is a solution, but I would prefer to test it anyway to avoid NPE in case someone forgot to do "conversion" in one of the "source places".

Comment: What about elvis ? (" ?: ") i mean

someNumber = whatEver ?: 0

Comment: Using Google Guava you can write `Integer i = MoreObjects.firstNonNull( possibleNull, 0);`

Comment: @brso05: The problem with this is that it takes three lines, and I need to repeat it many times. Since I know that I want to get in case of null value, why would I ever test it? Some implicit conversion should be possible.

Comment: @walkeros "it takes three lines" is not a good reason...You can create a method to handle this so you pass the method the `Integer` value and it changes it to 0 if its null.  You do not have to repeat the code you only need to write it once.

Comment: @walkeros "why would I ever test it" you would test it because you only want to convert `null` values to 0 not 5 not 7 not 9 etc...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: For now this idea of passing Optional<Number> instead of Integer/Long is worth considering I have to say. However when I get the numbers for example from REST call I use Jackson ObjectMapper to automatically map them. As I now read in Jackson docs I can probably map this automatically to Optional: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8 . I'll give this a try in a second.

Comment: @walkeros That sounds as if you want to pass an object resulting from mapping a JSON argument passed in through a REST service into some business logic? Very bad idea! I fear, you have much more design issues than discussed here.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: You are wrong. I get the number from REST and map it to Pojo. This pojo is immutable, so there is no problem to pass it to business logic. Purists would convert this object to some bussiness DTO, but this is not needed in case the mapped object is immutable. There is no design issue here.

Comment: @biziclop: I like this solution.  I'll probably go either for what Seelenvirtuose suggested or for the guava util that you suggested. I have to say I couldn't find ready util matching this use case. This one seems nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: If you want you can post your explanation as and answer to the problem ("If you design a method that simply cannot accept a null value, then just do not allow it"), I will accept it as a solution because this is the best in my particular case.

Answer (score 4):

Use  `i = (i==null)?0:i;`

- one line check
- no method call
- plain and simple
- no additional dependency (unlike some other proposed solutions)

Place this check as close to your numbers source as possible, to avoid unnecessary duplications.

Answer (score 2):

**By creating overloaded versions of Null Checker**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Integer intObj = null;
    System.out.println("intObj : " + checkNull(intObj));

    intObj = 1122222;
    System.out.println("intObj : " + checkNull(intObj));

    Long longObj = null;
    System.out.println("longObj : " + checkNull(longObj));

    longObj = 666555556L;
    System.out.println("longObj : " + checkNull(longObj));

    System.out.println("*********With default value***********");

    intObj = null;
    System.out.println("intObj : " + checkNull(intObj, 1));

    intObj = 1122222;
    System.out.println("intObj : " + checkNull(intObj, 1));

    longObj = null;
    System.out.println("longObj : " + checkNull(longObj, 0L));

    longObj = 666555556L;
    System.out.println("longObj : " + checkNull(longObj, 0L));
}

static Integer checkNull(Integer obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return 0;
    return obj;
}

static Long checkNull(Long obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return 0L;
    return obj;
}

static Integer checkNull(Integer obj, int i) {
    if (obj == null)
        return i;
    return obj;
}

static Long checkNull(Long obj, long l) {
    if (obj == null)
        return l;
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to write a utility method like below:

```
public static Integer checkNullNumber(Integer i){
if(i == null)
   return 0;
return i;
}
```

Now you can use this method wherever you want like:

```
zeroOrNull = checkNullNumber(zeroOrNull);
```

Comment: I already mentioned it as "version3". There problem with your static method is that it only accepts Integers and I can have Longs. This can be fixes with Number type. This is and option, but if I would go for it I would prefer some external lib.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't like to write three lines of code for such simple task,
>   especially because I need to do it many times

if (zeroOrNull == null) zeroOrNull = 0;

> I don't like to to "mutate" someNumber (assign new value to someNumber
>   variable)

there is no way to change the null-value into a "0" without constructing a new Integer object that holds this "0" and this single line of code does just that

Comment: The solution by plastique performs an assignment to "i" in the "else" case and therefor is less efficient than a simple "if" check.

Answer (score -1):

> Use java8 java.util.Optional class is very efficient, but don't use
>   explicit null values, use empty Optional

This is my original answer, if "efficient" was intended only by "performance" I've wronged word, sorry.

The mean is that all coding process is better, develop and execution are more safe.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Comment: The values comes from external source, do you want me to wrap them into Optional? I already gave an example of `Optional.ofNullable(zeroOrNull).orElseGet(() -> 0)` Is that what you mean? And why do you say it is very efficient? Can you prove it?

Comment: 1) OP already mentioned the alternative `Optional`. Why do you suggest it? What is the benefit? 2) What brought you to the statement that it "is very efficient"? Where is this efficiency? Any sources? Sorry, this is not a good answer, so I had to downvote.

Comment: my answer is based on your code, you set zeroOrNull to null then use Optional utils to compare values, is a nonsense. If you have different scenario post real code. The efficenty is not my opinion, but from Oracle articles that expose the introduction of the new API

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose he ask which solution is better, and I've answered, he didn't ask for a new one. Beneficts are exposed by Oracle articles, I can copy and paste the text here

Comment: @fantarama: If you say something is efficient you need to post a link to article (or another proof) together with your answer, otherwise this answer is not good.

Comment: @walkeros well so all answer here need the proof to be good, maybe "efficient" is a reserved word, sorry. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html